# PIG - matching toDate function

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to cast a string into a datetime object in hadoop pig. But Grunt give me a strange error message : it is like It can't choose the correct 'ToDate' function. It is asking for an 'explicit cast', but I have no clue how to do so. Any idea ?

=> ERROR 1045:  Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

```
grunt> describe infos_by_nu_affa;
infos_by_nu_affa: {NU_AFFA: bytearray,affaires: {(NU_AFFA:bytearray,NU_PCP: bytearray,debut: bytearray,fin: bytearray)},prestations: {(NU_AFFA: bytearray,montant: bytearray,date: bytearray,NU_presta: bytearray,beneficiaire: bytearray)},clients: {(NU_PCP: bytearray,nom: bytearray,prenom: bytearray)}}


derivees = foreach infos_by_nu_affa  generate *, ToDate(affaires.debut, 'dd/MM/yyyy') as (debut:datetime);
2015-03-28 15:46:36,089 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1045: <line 155, column 0> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.


grunt> dump infos_by_nu_affa
(affaire5,{(affaire5,client5,01/01/14,05/01/15)},{},{(client5,enders,kililan)})
(affaire6,{(affaire6,client6,01/01/13,01/06/14)},{},{(client6,blanco,martine)})
(affaire7,{(affaire7,client7,01/01/10,02/03/13)},{},{(client7,sarah,moore)})
(affaire8,{(affaire8,client8,01/01/15,01/01/01)},{},{(client8,evrard,dominique)})



grunt> derivees = foreach infos_by_nu_affa 
>> generate *,
>> COUNT(prestations) as nb_prestations,
>> ToDate(affaires.debut, 'dd/MM/yy') as debut;
2015-03-28 15:56:06,729 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1045: 
<line 155, column 0> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are passing `bag datatype(ie,affaires.debut)` as input to the `ToDate` function but `Todate` function will accept only `chararray or byterarray` as input. To solve this issue, you need to `flatten` the `(affaires.debut)` before passing to the `ToDate` function. It should be  something like this

```
derivees_temp = foreach infos_by_nu_affa  generate *,FLATTEN(affaires.debut) as (debut_temp:chararray);
derivees = foreach derivees_temp  generate *, ToDate(debut_temp, 'dd/MM/yyyy') as (debut:datetime);
```

**Note**: In the first stmt(`ie,derivees_temp`), after flattening the  datatype for `debut_temp` is `chararray` and the second stmt(`ie, derivees`) after `ToDate` the datatype  for `debut` is `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

We get these kind of exception when we doesn't pass correct argument type for the function. You are also facing same here. **ToDate** function support various type of argument please refer the [link](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/ToDate.html) and correct the code as per your need.